# iOS Orientation messed up on connection to UIViewController.view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers in my app, and 2 views. 1st view is black, 2nd view is white. 
The orientation is landscape mode, and the main (1st) view works ok.

So I created a second view controller, made the orientation in ib for it landscape, and connected the 2nd view to it via IB. 
[image]

I realised that the moment I connect the view, the orientation is messed up. It seems like the app is displaying the 2nd view in potrait mode instead. But nowhere in IB are my views in potrait mode.

I should get this. (I can get it by disconnecting the 2nd view from the 2nd viewcontroller, but that's not really what I want.

[image]

But I am getting this. 
[image]

This should be straightforward but it seems like it's not. 
How do I fix this? I've tried putting

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

in both viewControllers but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the autoresize mask.

[image]

Somehow if the arrows are not selected I get the undesirable result. It's fixed but I'm not quite sure why.

I'll be glad to accept the answer for anyone who can explain this to me. :)